# MATLAB ismember() problem

Tags: matlab, floating-point

The following command returns 1:

```
ismember(-0.6, -1:.1:.9)
```

but this next command returns 0:

```
ismember(-0.1, -1:.1:.9)
```

even though -0.1 clearly is in -1:.1:.9.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you start at -1.0 and add 0.1 repeatedly you get a slightly different number than if you specify -0.1 directly. This is because of floating-point error accumulation. Just like 1/3 cannot be represented exactly in decimal (it becomes 0.33333...), many decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary. 0.1 when converted to binary is actually a very close approximation to 0.1. Because there is a slight error when you do arithmetic with this floating point number this small difference accumulates and becomes bigger and bigger.

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246492:

> Ashwini Deshpande wrote:
>
> > ---
> >
> > I have a matrix as follows,
> >
> > ```
> > a = 0:0.1:1;
> > ```
> >
> > when I tried to find whether 0.300 is present in the matrix `a`, using the following procedure,
> >
> > ```
> > >> [tf, loc]=ismember(0.3,a)
> > ```
> >
> > I got the following result:
> >
> > ```
> > tf =
> >      0
> > loc =
> >      0
> > ```
> >
> > But it's suppose to give me, `tf = 1` and `loc =4`.
> >
> > ---
>
> You're getting the *correct* result, actually. Look what happens:
>
> ```
>      v=0:.1:1;
>      n=0.3;
>      sprintf('%30.20f\n',v(4),n)
> %{
>      0.30000000000000004000 % <- result from vec
>      0.29999999999999999000 % <- result from handwritten number
> %}
>      format hex;
>      [v(4),n,v(4)-n].'
> %{
>      3fd3333333333334 % <- vec
>      3fd3333333333333 % <- num
>      3c90000000000000 % <- diff
> %}
>      format;
> ```
>
> Also, peruse http://matlabwiki.mathworks.com/MATLAB_FAQ#Why_is_0.3-0.2-0.1_not_equal_to_zero_.28or_similar.29.3F

Answer (score 4):

Floating point error.

The number 0.1 is REALLY REALLY CLOSE to the value in the vector, but not exactly.  Some numbers can not be represented exactly in a binary computer.

What are you trying to do exactly, there are many thresholding techniques that can work here if we know your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a consequence of [floating point representations for numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), in that the number 0.1 is not exactly representable as a floating point value. The [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) used to generate the vector does so through successive additions of the value 0.1 and accumulates very small errors in the process. The value in the vector that you think is -0.1 is actually slightly different from -0.1 due to these errors, and is also different from the value of -0.1 that results when you declare it directly. Take this example:

```
>> format long   % Changes display to show more decimal places
>> vec = -1:0.1:0.9;
>> vec(10)+0.1

ans =

    2.775557561562891e-017
```

Notice that you don't get 0 as an answer, since the -0.1 in the vector is ever so slightly different in absolute value from the 0.1 you are adding to it. However, if you were to create your vector *without* using the colon operator, you would get the answer you desire:

```
>> vec = [-1 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0 ...
          0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9];
>> ismember(-0.1,vec)

ans =

     1
```

In short, explicitly declaring a value of -0.1 gives an ever-so-slightly different number than generating the value of -0.1 through successively adding 0.1 to -1.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way around this problem is to round your array before comparing.
For FKT 100 this would give you an array that is quantized at 2 decimals.

round(FKT.*data)./FKT